# if and elif doesn't work in template django

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

if and elif doesn't work in my template django

index.html

```
<a style="{% if show.Ages == 19 %}background:#ff3636;{% elif show.Ages == 17 %}background:#fb9c92;{% elif show.Ages == 13 %}background:#ffb466;{% else %}background:#4aff68;{% endif %};border-radius: 15px;width: 140px;height: 42;margin-right: 831px;margin-top: -200;" class="button">رده‌ سنی‌:+{{ show.Ages }}</a>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    shows = show.objects.all()
    context = {
        'shows':shows
    }
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class show(models.Model):
    Ages = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='',null=True)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Why are you missing the colons `:`?

Comment: It's `shows` not `show`.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but consider renaming `show` to `Show` and `Ages` to `ages`. When Python developers see a capital letter they think "class", not "attribute". The [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) contains other suggestions.

Comment: {% if show.Ages == 19 %}                                                                             
to                                                                     
{% if show.Ages ==  "19" %}                                                                  
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `show.Ages` attribute is a `CharField`, not an `IntegerField`. Instead of comparing it against integers you should compare it against strings, e.g.

```
{% if show.Ages == '17' %}...{% endif %}
```

As pointed out in the comments your context variable is `shows`, not `show`, but I suspect that your template snippet already lives inside something like

```
{% for show in shows %}...{% endfor %}
```

which would create a `show` loop variable.